# Pass a Bean name from properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties

Is it possible to pass a class or Bean name from properties file in spring boot. If so how can we read it from the controller? I am using @Value annotation with SPL expressions.
Here is what I was trying to do.

applicaiton.properties

```
api.ldap.searchclasses= foo.classes.class1,foo.classes.class2
```

and in the controller

```
class Controller {

@Value("#{'$(api.ldap.searchclasses}'.split(','}"} Iterable<SearchClassInterface> searchClasses;

}
```

where foo.classes.class1,foo.classes.class2 extends SearchClassInterface.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] and make sure your question is readable by marking code as code. Also `applicaiton.properties` is certainly wrong.

Comment: Can you give some more background about what you are trying to accomplish ?